# Node.js string to byte[] is not equivalent to Java

Tags: java, node.js, string, byte, md5

In `Node.js`, I thought converting a `string` to a `byte[]` would work, but the result is not the same as the result in `Java`.

string = "123456"

`Java` result:

> md5: e10adc3949ba59abbe56e057f20f883e
>
> byte[]: [-31, 10, -36, 57, 73, -70, 89, -85, -66, 86, -32, 87, -14, 15, -120, 62]

`Node.js` result:

> md5: e10adc3949ba59abbe56e057f20f883e
>
> byte[]: [101, 49, 48, 97, 100, 99, 51, 57, 52, 57, 98, 97, 53, 57, 97, 98, 98, 101, 53, 54, 101, 48, 53, 55, 102, 50, 48, 102, 56, 56, 51, 101]

In `Node.js`, I start with an `md5` `string`, then convert the `string` to a `byte[]`, but the result != `Java` result.

`Node.js` code:

```
var bytes = []
var buff = new Buffer(str, encoding)
for (var i = 0; i < buff.length; i ++) {
  var byteint = buff[i]
  bytes.push(byteint)
}
return bytes
```

Answer (score 0):

[image]

[image]

Maybe it's about `encoding`

Set it and try again?